# Link in flask and jquery

Tags: python, jquery, flask

I started to learn flask, but some things still confuse me. I have an ajax call to a route in the flask, the method does everything and returns a path (/modules/analysis/reports/arquivo.html), I retrieve this link in jquery(success) and make a list with this link and a method to open this link.

The problem is when I try to open it, when I click on the link the address is: 127.0.0.1:5000/modules/analysis/reports/arquivo.html so it didn't work.

What should I do? Make a route and another ajax call?

The entire interface is being managed by html5 and jquery, I'm not using jinja. If it was localhost it would work, but the server generated by flask didn't work.